# Convert list to column in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:

```
CustomerId    Age
1              25
2              18
3              45
4              57
5              34
```

I have a list called "Price" which looks like this:

```
Price = [123,345,1212,11,677]
```

I want to add that list to the dataframe. Here is my code:

```
df['Price'] = Price
```

It seems to work but when I print the dataframe the field called "Price" contains all the metadata information such as Name, Type... as well as the value of the Price.

How can I create a column called "Price" containing only the values of the Price list so that the dataframe looks like:

```
CustomerId    Age   Price
1              25   123
2              18   345
3              45   1212
4              57   11
5              34   677
```

Comment: Please include your code, otherwise you are expecting people to guess what you wrote so that they can guess where you made an error.

Comment: What solution was the one that worked???

Comment: _It seems to work but when I print the dataframe the field called "Price" contains all the metadata information such as Name, Type... as well as the value of the Price._ I know this question is old, but that makes little sense. We need a [mcve] or this is pointless.

Answer (score 23):

In my Opinion, the most elegant solution is to use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(Price=Price)
CustomerId    Age   Price
1              25   123
2              18   345
3              45   1212
4              57   11
5              34   677
```

note that assign actually **returns** a DataFrame.
Assign creates a new Column 'Price' (left Price) with the content of the list Price (right Price)

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
df['Price'] = pd.Series(Price)
```

if you use this you will not get the error if you have less values in the series than to your dataframe otherwise you will get the error that will tell you have less vales in the list and that can not be appended.

Answer (score 4):

I copy pasted your example into a dataframe using pandas.read_clipboard and then added the column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
Price = [123,345,1212,11,677]
df.loc[:,'Price'] = Price
df
```

Generating this:

```
CustomerId  Age Price
0   1   25  123
1   2   18  345
2   3   45  1212
3   4   57  11
4   5   34  677
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add pandas series as column.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Price'] = pd.Series(Price)
```